# Language code and country code on the URL

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've been trying to achieve this:

I have a multilingual site with 8 languages (en, fr, es, de, etc) and I want to make all those language available for all countries.

I want Drupal to understand that:

- /en-CO alias of /en
- /en-FR alias of /en
- /es-US alias of /es
- /es-AR alias of /es
- /fr-CO alias of /fr
- /de-US alias of /de

And so on... (They share the exact same content)

If I add all those custom languages is easy, but I don't want because more than 1600 combinations are posible.

Do you know if there is a way to achieve that programmatically or with a module ?

I'm currently looking into PathProcessor, but no result for now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question though is: Why? And if it wouldn't be better to have a proper hreflang setup in your HTML head.

Comment: I guess you already know that you can manually add aliases, but per page, at admin page:
/admin/config/search/path

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using Persistent URLs: https://www.drupal.org/project/purl and a custom LanguageNegotiation plugin